# Using Configuration in PHP

Tags: php, logging, error-handling, syslog

Where i need to place my "myScriptLog" Log File and what are the confogurations to Log the PHP Application

 Below is the Sample Syslog Code

```
openlog("myScriptLog", LOG_PID | LOG_PERROR, LOG_LOCAL0);                            

if (authorized_client()) {
   // do something
} else {
    // unauthorized client!
    // log the attempt
    $access = date("Y/m/d H:i:s");
    syslog(LOG_WARNING, "Unauthorized client: $access {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']} ({$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']})");
}
closelog();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you

http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/12157.html

use the above class to log the sys errors

Comment: Thanks Codesen,i think that log message write to that server
RFC 3164 compliant syslog server that they are mentioned

Comment: http://www.winsyslog.com/common/en/stepbystep/how-to-setup-phpsyslogng-with-monitorware-products.php

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `error_log`?  http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php

Then you can specify the destination:

```
bool error_log ( string $message [, int $message_type = 0 [, string $destination [, string $extra_headers ]]] )
```

EDIT: Or you could use syslog: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.syslog.php then your logs will just go to syslog instead of `myScriptLog` (depends what you need).

Does that help?

Comment: I need to capture all errors through syslog only, In syslog where i can give the destination?

Comment: `syslog` in Linux normally in `/var/log/messages` `/var/log/syslog`.  Are you working with Linux?  PHP docs say "On Windows NT, the syslog service is emulated using the Event Log."

Comment: No am Working on Windows, yes, the syslog captures the error in Event Viewer in Windows, how can keep the log file which capture all the errors using syslog?

Comment: Hmm maybe you would be better using the first option (`error_log`) otherwise you're going to need to translate from Windows event messages to syslog which would probably require some other tool.  Go to your `php.ini` file and look for the `error_log` directive.  Specify a destination here and you should be done.

Comment: Thanks ale, do you have any idea about Windows event messages to syslog conversion tool?

Comment: Hm, I don't use Windows so I'm not sure.  However, sounds like `error_log` might be an easier option?